# 並行リダクション用Collectorでcombiner関数の実装は必須？

Tags: java, java8

Java8のSteam APIで[並行リダクション(concurrent reduction)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#ConcurrentReduction)をサポートした自作Collectorを作るとき、Collectorの[combiner関数](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html#combiner--)が**呼ばれることはない**と仮定しても良いものでしょうか？

（実効的な意味はない）下記サンプルコードでは、自作Collectorは`CONCURRENT`かつ`UNORDERED`特性を持っており：

- 並列ストリーム(`parallel()`あり)なら並列リダクション = supplier関数があるスレッド上で1回呼ばれる＋各Workerスレッドから並行にaccumulator関数が呼ばれる
- 逐次ストリーム(`parallel()`なし)なら単一スレッド上のリダクション = supplier関数＋accumulator関数が単一スレッドから呼ばれる

と期待されるため、いずれのケースでもcombiner関数が使われる事は無いと考えられます。

```
import java.util.stream.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.*;

public class DoesConcReductionCollectorNeedsCombiner {
  static public void main(String[] args) {
    ConcurrentMap<Integer, AtomicInteger> result =
      IntStream.range(1, 10_000_001).boxed()  // Stream<Integer>
        .parallel()  // 並列ストリーム化
        .collect(Collector.of(
          () -> new ConcurrentHashMap<>(),
          (m,v) -> {
            AtomicInteger a = m.putIfAbsent(v % 10, new AtomicInteger(v));
            if (a != null)
              a.getAndAdd(v);
          },
          (m,n) -> {
            // 並行リダクションなら呼び出されない? = 実装不要?
            // （まじめに実装するなら2つの並行Mapのマージが必要）
            System.out.println("!");
            return null;
          },
          Collector.Characteristics.CONCURRENT,
          Collector.Characteristics.UNORDERED
        ));
    System.out.println("r="+result);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[java.util.stream (Java Platform SE 8 )](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)

> *Reduction, concurrency, and ordering*
>
> Suppose, however, that the result container used in this reduction was a concurrently modifiable collection -- such as a ConcurrentHashMap. In that case, the parallel invocations of the accumulator could actually deposit their results concurrently into the same shared result container, **eliminating the need for the combiner to merge distinct result containers**. This potentially provides a boost to the parallel execution performance. We call this a concurrent reduction.
> A Collector that supports concurrent reduction is marked with the Collector.Characteristics.CONCURRENT characteristic. However, a concurrent collection also has a downside. If multiple threads are depositing results concurrently into a shared container, the order in which results are deposited is non-deterministic. Consequently, a concurrent reduction is only possible if ordering is not important for the stream being processed.

上記の様に記載されていますので、仰っしゃるとおりに combiner 関数が呼ばれることはないでしょう。

Comment: 逐次ストリームへも言及があるか気になったのですが、同ページに"The _combiner_ function combines two partial results to produce a new partial result. (The combiner is necessary in parallel reductions, where the input is partitioned, a partial accumulation computed for each partition, and then the partial results are combined to produce a final result.)"とあり、こちらもcombiner関数が利用されることは無さそうです。

Answer (score 3):

仮定してもいいです。

並列リダクション(concurrency reduction)を行うと判断するために、 Java8 ランタイムは３条件をみます。Concurrency reduction が起こった場合は、 combiner が利用されません。このことは [JavaDoc に記載](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#package.description)されています。

- ストリームが parallel であること
- コレクタが concurrent であること
- ストリームが unordered か、 コレクタが unordered 特性をもつこと

ただし、悩ましいことがあります。私の回答としては、「 combiner は利用されない、しかし実装しなければならない。」です。API で期待されている実装の一部を抜くというのは、好ましくないという単純な理由からです。

Java8 の Stream API の設計思想に「順列と並列でAPIの利用方法が同一であること」があります。ですので、使用されないとあなたが判断できる場合でも、APIの呼び出し手順を満たすために実装しなければならない、という状態になっています。ですので、空の実装にするのではなく、動くコードを書いておくべきだと思います。（当然テスト対象になり得ます・・・gaaah）

サンプルの例のようにプログラムが一画面におさまり、combiner の実装を利用者が認識できる状態なら問題はないでしょうけどね。

参考:

- [Setting of UNORDERED on concurrent collectors](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-libs-spec-experts/2013-April/001599.html)
- [State of the Lambda: Libraries Edition - Background](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-libraries-final.html)